# How to convert Collection<Set<String>> into String Array

Tags: java, collections

*When I am trying to convert, I am getting below exception*

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.util.HashSet
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(Unknown Source)
```

*This is my code*

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
String[] keySet = map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.size()]);
Collection<Set<String>> collections = map.values();
String[] values = collection.toArray(new String[collection.size()]);// In this line getting Exception
```

Comment: What is the desired result? Please give an example of original collection and desired array contents.

Comment: I was at first surprised that your code compiled at all. It should be known at compile time that no `Set` can be cast to `String`, so storing the sets from your original collection into a string array would be sure to fail. However, the argument is hard to generalize, so `Collection.toArray` accepts any array type on compile time (and will probably succeed even with incompatible types if the collection is empty or contains only nulls).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`Stream.flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) as you stream over the `values` to collect them later into an array. This can be done as:

```
String[] values = map.values().stream()
                  .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                  .toArray(String[]::new);
```

***Note***: The reason why your code compiles successfully even with

```
toArray(new String[collection.size()])
```

is that [`Collection.toArray(T[] a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)) because its hard for the compiler to determine the type prior to execution for a generic type. This is the same reason why even

```
Integer[] values = collections.toArray(new Integer[collections.size()]);
```

would compile in your case, but as you can now clearly see that nowhere in your collections do you have an `Integer` type. Hence at *runtime*, a new array is allocated *with the runtime type of the specified array* and the size of this collection.

That is where the `ArrayStoreException` in your case results from since now you have a type mismatch as your collection is of type `Set<String>` instead of `String`.

***Important***: You cannot possibly [convert to a generic array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java) as you may further think of.

Answer (score 3):

What you're attempting to do is not possible. This is made explicit in the documentation.

The `toArray` method is documented to throw a [`java.lang.ArrayStoreException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray-T:A-):

> if the runtime type of the specified array is not a supertype of the
>   runtime type of every element in this collection

instead, what you can do is create a stream from the map values, flatMap it! (i.e. collapse the nested sequences) then collect to an array:

```
 map.values()  // Collection<Set<String>>
    .stream()  // Stream<Set<String>>
    .flatMap(Collection::stream) // Stream<String>
    .toArray(String[]::new); // String[]
```